# How to translate a touch event on screen to SeekBar progress?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a (vertical) SeekBar that gets it's progress according to the Y value of a touch event, on touch somewhere on the screen, so that if the touch is above the seekbar, it's progress is 100, if the touch is below the seekbar and otherwise the seekbar's thumb should be at the same line of the touch on screen.

How such thing could be done?

Example:

[image: Vertical SeekBar example]

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but a simple one would be adding two empty views, one above and one below the SeekBar. You would be able then to detect the onClick on each view and change the SeekBar's progress manually.

Example:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:rotation="270"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
findViewById(R.id.view_top).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(YOUR_MAX_PROGRESS);
    }
});

findViewById(R.id.view_bottom).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(YOUR_MIN_PROGRESS);
    }
});
```

Edit: I'm currently missing the detection on the sides of the SeekBar

Comment: Yeah, that's a simple solution, but with few problems... What if i touch the upper area and then drag to the bottom? The seekbar value will remain 100%